# JSON.parse error....unexpected token{ from 2nd

Tags: javascript, json

My JSON.parse is successful when it is called first. But from 2nd call, unexpected token error occurs.
I found from the search in stackoverflow some explanation for other's question below..

"If you parse it again it will perform a toString-cast first so you're parsing something like "[object Object"] which explains the unexpected token o "

How can i make the fresh parse. my code is like below.

```
var musicEntry="";

function parsing(){
     ...
     for(var i=0;i<musicList.length;i++){
        musicEntry=musicEntry+ '{"fileName":"'+musicList[i].title+'"},';
     }
      .....

      var musicJsonObjString='{"music":['+ musicEntry +']}';  
      musicJsonObj=JSON.parse(musicJsonObjString);

}
```

Comment: If you're only in JavaScript, do you need to actually build the string only to then parse it?  It would make more sense to just build the object directly, then `JSON.stringify` it if you actually need the string representation

Comment: Why in the world are you building a string to start with?

Comment: `musicJsonObj+=` wouldn't be better?

Comment: I recommend to read a JavaScript tutorial, such as https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) instead of trying to write your own JSON encoder. Whilst your approach might now work with the trailing comma issue fixed, you'll also need to guard against reserved characters in your music title attribute.

Simply build a JavaScript object (or array) and give it to JSON.stringify(obj)

Working example

```
var musicList = [{
    title: 'foo'
}, {
    title: 'bar'
}];

var array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < musicList.length; i++) {
    array.push({fileName: musicList[i].title})
}

var musicJsonObjString = JSON.stringify({music: array});
var musicJsonObj = JSON.parse(musicJsonObjString);
console.log("music", musicJsonObj);
```

Comment: Really Thank you. I changed mine with your suggestion of array.push. Now resolved : )

Comment: @LoganYoon no worries

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove last comma from your array:

```
var musicJsonObjString='{"music":[' + musicEntry.substr(0, musicEntry.length - 1 ) + ']}';
```

Comment: Yes.. I omitted. My code has that .. musicEntry = musicEntry.substring(0, musicEntry.length - 1); after completion of for loop.

Comment: So your problem seems to be in other place. Show us full code or jsFiddle